# What does "decoherence attenuates the density matrix" mean?

Tags: density-matrix, quantum-fourier-transform, experimental-realization

I'm reading the paper [*Implementation of the Quantum Fourier Transform*](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906059). On page 4, they write

> To a first approximation, decoherence during the course of the QFT attenuates the entire density matrix. This is shown in figure 2.

I know that the word "attenuate" means to dampen or reduce the force of something. Since density operators have trace one, perhaps this means that the QFT decreases the trace of the density operator.

**My question is:** What is meant by attenuate here?

Comment: I'd guess what is meant is that decoherence decreases the off-diagonal elements of the density matrix.

Comment: And please link to the abstract rather than the PDF - this is extremely annoying if one is just interested in knowing what paper that is.

Comment: +1 but I've reduced it to one question since we have a policy to ask only one question per post. You can ask another question or edit the question to switch to the other question if you want.